# How do I call a generic interface method from another generic class

Tags: java, generics, interface

Here is my code.
I have a generic interface

```
public interface ClientServerComparator<T> {
    public boolean compare(T entity,T obj);
}
```

I am trying to implement another generic class

```
public class EntityTest<T> {

  public void testPutObject(Client client, T obj ) throws UnExpectedStatusException 
    {
        log.debug("PUT: " + location);
      T entity = testGetObject(client,entityLocation,l);

     if(entity instanceof ClientServerComparator<?> )
     {
        if( false ==  ((ClientServerComparator<?>) entity).compare(entity,obj) )
        {
            log.error("Object fetched back does not match object put");
            throw new UnExpectedStatusException();
        }

     }

    }
```

I receive the following compiler error:

```
The method compare(capture#1-of ?, capture#1-of ?) in the type 
ClientServerComparator<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (T, T)
```

How do I make the `EntityTest` generic class call a method on an object that implements `ClientServerComparator` generic interface?

Comment: Instead of ClientServerComparator<?> cast to ClientServerComparator<T>.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the wildcard you are using tells the compiler, that entity is any ClientServerComparator, not necessarily related to T.

However, you already know that entity is of type T (which you have defined by the type annotation where you instantiate entity). Also, you are checking whether entity is an instance of ClientServerComparator. I am assuming, that you always expect entity to be an instance of ClientServerComparator. If this is the case, then you can change the generic type of EntityTest to `<T extends ClientServerComparator<T>>` and get rid of the instanceof check and the type cast:

```
public class EntityTest<T extends ClientServerComparator<T>> {

    public void testPutObject(Client client, T obj) {
        T entity = testGetObject(client);

        if (entity.compare(entity, obj)) {
            throw new UnExpectedStatusException();
        }

    }
}
```

Now T is a `ClientServerComparator<T>`, hence you can call compare on entity.

Comment: Thanks Kulu. Your suggestion does work but I wanted the EntityTest class to be flexible and call the compare function only when T implements ClientServerComparator interface

Answer (score 0):

`T` is a type variable in both your class `EntityTest` and in `ClientServerComparator`. But it's a *variable* and that means that it doesn't denote the same type in your two classes. You could have called `T` by another name like `Z` in `ClientServerComparator` and it would not change anything about the meaning of your code.

So, to invoke the `compare` method on two objects of type variable `T`, you first need to cast your object to `ClientServerComparator<T>` instead of `ClientServerComparator<?>`. In the latter case, it doesn't know what the type is (`<?>`) so you cannot invoke any methods with arguments of the generic type [you can only invoke methods that return the generic type]

If you cast to `(ClientServerComparator<T>)` you will get a warning from the compiler about an "unchecked cast". This is because in Java, generics are only compile-time type-safe. At runtime, the actual value of type variable `T` is not known anymore.

So technically it is possible that you have a class `Foo` that implements `ClientServerComparator<Bar>`. If you know that you don't ever have this in your code, you can suppress that compiler warning with the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation.

Like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void testPutObject(Client client, T obj) throws UnExpectedStatusException {
    T entity = testGetObject(client, entityLocation, l);

    if (entity instanceof ClientServerComparator) {
        if (false == ((ClientServerComparator<T>) entity).compare(entity, obj)) {
            throw new UnExpectedStatusException();
        }
    }

}
```